# BluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices returns 0 size of BluetoothDevice list

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I've connected two Android phones. One is server while the other is client. As they're in connected state, client will try to get BluetoothHeadset by getProfileProxy(). But it can just get 0 connected BluetoothDevice. I expected the server can be a headset because Android supports BluetoothHeadset includes both Bluetooth Headset and Handsfree (v1.5) profiles. So client's supposed to get at least 1 connected BluetoothDevice with BluetoothHeadset.

```
private void methodx() { mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(xx.this, mBluetoothProfileServiceListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET); }

private BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;
private BluetoothDevice mBluetoothHeadsetDevice;

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mBluetoothProfileServiceListener =
        new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
                mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
                List<BluetoothDevice> deviceList = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices();
                if (deviceList.size() > 0) {
                    mBluetoothHeadsetDevice = deviceList.get(0);
                } else {
                    mBluetoothHeadsetDevice = null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
                if (mBluetoothHeadset != null) {
                    List<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothHeadset.getConnectedDevices();
                    if (devices.size() == 0) {
                        mBluetoothHeadsetDevice = null;
                    }
                    mBluetoothHeadset = null;
                }
            }
        };
```

After some days of research, I found out this is not a easy task. Currently, Android do support HSP & HFP, but it plays a Audio Gate Way role. While a bluetooth headset plays a Headset role. It's not possible to accomplish this task in Application level, but need to research more about Bluedroid (Android BT stack) and BT device driver. Basically, it needs a customized ROM.